# Iteration for the definition of a function

Tags: python, function, loops

I would like to make an iteration in order to get a function verifying an integral equation. The integral operator is hidden in the function `lambdaop`. However, I just cannot iterate on the process getting an error

> File "blablabla/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 11, in integrand
>       return -0.5*f(x)*scipy.special.expi(-abs(x-tau))
>
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

that I do not understand. I have done here for only two functions by my ultimate goal would be to make n iteration. I guess the error comes from the way of defining the function that is not suitable (maybe not use "lambda definitions" ... ) but I do not want to create a vector of size n in place of the function since I want to integrate it after. Anyone has an idea how to fix this problem ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import scipy.integrate
import scipy.special

def initial(x):
    return x + 2/3

def integrand(f,x,tau):
    return -0.5*f(x)*scipy.special.expi(-abs(x-tau))

def lambdaop(f,x,tau):
    def step(x,tau):
        return integrand(f,x,tau)
    g = lambda tau: scipy.integrate.quad(step,0,np.inf,args=(tau,))
    return g

g = lambdaop(initial,1,2)
h = lambdaop(g,1,2)
print(h(5))

x = np.linspace(0,3,101)
y = np.linspace(0,3,101)
for i in np.arange(101):
     y[i] = h(x[i])[0]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I have not seen any other topic like mine but in case it is a duplicate, please excuse me.

Answer (score 1):

Add some print statements in your `integrand` function.

For example,

```
def integrand(f,x,tau):
    print('-------')
    print('args:', f, x, tau)
    v = f(x)
    print(f'f({x})={v}')
    s = scipy.special.expi(-abs(x-tau))
    print(f's={s}')
    result = -0.5*v*s
    print('=====')
    return result
```

and you'll see that:

```
f(1.0)=(inf, inf)
s=-0.0037793524098489063
```

The `(inf, inf)` is where the error message is coming from.